# Failing to compile GTest with Cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, googletest

I'm new to C++, I am trying to compile gtest with Cygwin. I have installed the GNU g++ compiler which works fine. I ran the following command on Cygwin:

g++ -I /cygdrive/c/devel/cpp/gtest/include -I /cygdrive/c/devel/cpp/gtest -pthread -c /cygdrive/c/devel/cpp/gtest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc
/cygdrive/c/devel/cpp/gtest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc:39:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

All the files seem to be in place, however the error does not go, any ideas why?

Comment: Check if the `-I` flags are correct.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have provided space between -I and path. 
There should not be any space between -I and corresponding path.

It should be like 
g++ -I/cygdrive/c/devel/cpp/gtest/include -I/cygdrive/c/devel/cpp/gtes..
Check it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I tried:         g++ -I/cygdrive/c/devel/cpp/gtest/include -I/cygdrive/c/devel/cpp/gtest -pthread -c /cygdrive/c/devel/cpp/gtest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc
/cygdrive/c/devel/cpp/gtest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc:39:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.        same error as you can see, do you perhaps have any clue what could still be wrong?

Comment: where is `gtest.h` ?

Comment: I would suggest to write a simple program .cpp and .h file (not related to gtest) and check if it compiles or not. 
I suspect it could be that cygwin not configured properly.